# Showing a value (instead of label) on a Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-typescript

So I have an async combo box that pulls options from an API. The options are just an Id and a description. This component is part of a form that I'm showing to add or edit data. What I'd like to see happen is have the option be empty when adding new data and to have the current value selected when editing. Instead, it simply shows the label.
This is my code that's almost a copypaste of the example from the docs.

```
export default function AsyncAutoComplete(props:AsyncAutoCompleteProps) {
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState<EntityWithIdAndDescription[]>([]);
const loading = open && options.length === 0;

React.useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;
    if (!loading) {
        return undefined;
    }
    (async () => {
        props.populateWith().then((options)=> {
            if (active) {
            setOptions(options);
        }})
    })();
    return () => {
        active = false;
    };
}, [loading]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!open) {
        setOptions([]);
    }
}, [open]);

return (

        <Autocomplete
            id="async-autocomplete"
            open={open}
            onOpen={() => {
                setOpen(true);
            }}
            onClose={() => {
                setOpen(false);
            }}
            onChange={props.onChange}
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.description}
            options={options}
            loading={loading}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label={props.label}
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="dense"
                    InputProps={{
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        endAdornment: (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ),
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
);
```

What I want is to pass an Id value to this component and have it show the description for that value as the selected option (after making the API call). Using defaultValue doesn't seem to work.
Any advice with either modifying this or taking a different approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like what you're after is a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). There's an example of this in [Material UI's Autocomplete demo under Playground called controlled](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#playground).

I'm not sure how you're getting the `id` of the initial value you want to pass to the component to show that it's selected. It could be something like the following.

1. Create a separate state for the value you select from this `Autocomplete` in your parent component. In fact, I would not have a separate component called `AsyncAutocomplete` at all. This is so you control all your state in the parent component and the `Autocomplete` component becomes purely presentational.
2. After your API call is complete and the `setOptions(options)` is called, call `setValue` with the value that you would like to show selected. This must be of type `EntityWithIdAndDescription`.
3. Create an inline-function for the `onChange` prop of the `Autocomplete` component which takes a the second parameter as the `EntityWithIdAndDescription | null` type. This is what's required  from `Autocomplete`'s `onChange`. Call `setValue` with this parameter as the argument.
4. Pass `options`, `value`, `onChange` and `loading` as props into the `Autocomplete` component. The additional props I've passed over and above what you've done in your code are:

```
<Autocomplete
    ...
    disabled={loading}
    value={value}
    ...
/>
```

Let me know how you go

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<EntityWithIdAndDescription | null>(null); // (1)

const [options, setOptions] = useState<EntityWithIdAndDescription[]>([]);

const loading = options.length === 0;

useEffect(() => {  
    populateWith().then((options)=> {
        setOptions(options);
    })
 
    // (2)
    setValue({
        id: "something",
        description: "something",
    })

    return () => {};
}, []); 

// (4)
 <Autocomplete
            id="async-autocomplete"
            disabled={loading}
            onChange={(event: any, newValue: EntityWithIdAndDescription | null) => {
                setValue(newValue); // (3)
            }}
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.description}
            options={options}
            loading={loading}
            value={value}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label={"My Entities"}
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="dense"
                    InputProps={{
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        endAdornment: (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ),
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
);
```

**Code Sandbox**

Here's an example with the `Autocomplete` in a separate component I called `MyAutocomplete`. It includes an API call and setting a value I want to be selected first.

https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-silence-lkjrf

Comment: Sadly, I couldn't make it work. For 1) I don't think I can get away with not having a separate component because I need to reuse that code a lot. 3) This is pretty much what I'm doing, passing an inline as a prop to set the value (this part works fine). 2) and 4) These are the main changes I tried to implement. I'm now making the API call on the parent component and passing options and a value as a prop, but the combo box still shows the label instead of the value I'm passing. Only after manually selecting an option and reopening the parent component it shows the current value as selected.

Comment: Definitely have it as a separate component if you'll be re-using that code a lot. Just double checking, are you passing in the value prop to the Autocomplete component? I created a Code Sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-silence-lkjrf with an API call as well and it worked for me. Also had the Autocomplete as a separate component. I'll edit my answer to highlight what I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm not 100% there but I marked this as answered because your Code Sandbox example behaves exactly like what I described. I think I should be able to use your code in my project. Thanks for the detailed answer and the code example.